# How to make an exceprt of an HTML element with complex content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have block containing text links and potentially images and other tags. I want to limit it to 300 characters with Javascript. But want to save links and other formatting, can omit images.

The idea of stripping all HTML tags is quite simple, but not perfect.
I like how wordpress create excertps.

Can someone provide good example of doing this using Javascript, didn't find any plugin or any other solution by a quick search.